# Select file path via GUI

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, gui

I would like to select my input file and output folder path via a GUI. At the moment, I simply defined my paths like this

```
#path to het input file
input_path = 'c:/Users/tobias/Desktop/object1/object2/inputfile.dxf'

#path for produced output file
output_path = 'c:/Users/tobias/Desktop/object1/object2/output_folder'
```

I would like to use 'QtGui' which is already implemented in PyQGIS. I try to implement it but I am pretty new in GUI programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a convenient way to get the directory via:

```
#start directory near to folder structure to save klicks

directory = 'c:/Users/tobias/Desktop/object1' 

#get the input path

input_path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open .dxf file', directory,'*.dxf')
```

A simple string operation gives me the output path directory.

```
#Gets the first part of the file directory from input and adds the output folder directory

split_input = input_path.rsplit("/",1)
output_path = split_input[0] + "/output_folder/"
```